# Can't force psexec to use the given user account

Tags: cmd, psexec, runas

I used to use `runas` for running my app under another user account. Now I need to pass the password through as well. I found that `psexec` is an easy way to do it.

So the batch file contains:

```
@echo off
psexec my.exe -u hostname\user -p password
```

The problem is `my.exe` is still being initiated under the user I'm currently logged onto the system with and not under the one declared in the cmd above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the program must be the last argument 
try this :

```
psexec -u hostname\user -p password my.exe
```

Comment: no way.... the examples on this page http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html shows exactly the opposite... Thank you mate!

Comment: nope, the examples are OK on this site, have a better look ;)

Comment: Like this: `psexec \\workstation64 -c test.exe -u DannyGlover -p Pa55w0rd`?

Comment: yep, they use -c **option** to copy test.exe  on the remote host then execute it